# Why am I getting Wrong type argument: stringp, nil?

Tags: debugging

What's wrong here ? It gives me the error `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

```lisp
(let* ((filename (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
       (executable (file-name-sans-extension filename)))
  (setq compile-command
        (concat "g++ -static -DONLINE_JUDGE -DONLINE_JUDGESAS -Wl,--stack=268435456 -O2 -std=c++17 "
                filename
                " -o "
                executable)))
```

Comment: Are you sure that buffer-file-name is bind to some file name in the environment you eval this form ? buffer-file-name is probably nil. You can trace the execution with Edebug if you are in Emacs-lisp mode.

Comment: This is no doubt a duplicate question, but I don't have the time to look for it. Hopefully someone will find it. Then this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: To add a bit to @gigiair's point, if you turn on `debug-on-error`, you get a backtrace that has more information than the bare error message. In this case I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-name-nondirectory(nil)` - that tells you that `file-name-nondirectory` was called with a `nil` argument (but it is expecting a string, hence the error).